# Allure report is returning "192.168.0.18 didn’t send any data."

Tags: selenium, rest-assured, allure

After running allure report locally, I get this page on chrome.

```
"192.168.0.18 didn’t send any data."
```

I have tried to see local folder, and it contains the data. And when I start the index.html, from allure report folder, I get the standard allure image where for each section "Loading" is displayed.

Did anyone face similar thing and can help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory where the allure items are put, usually it's `target/allure-results` , so try this one: `allure serve target/allure-results`

Or try to generate a report and then serve it:

- `allure generate target/allure-results`
- `allure serve target/allure-results`

Comment: no it does not help. But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the other port with:

```
allure serve -h localhost -p 8081 /your/folder/with/json/files
```

The report would open at http://localhost:8081/index.html